# How to make a plane mesh double sided?

Tags: mesh, unreal-engine

I have a simple pingpong table model. I use a plane mesh for the net part, but one side of it appears invisible when imported in unreal engine. Ive seen guides on how to fix it but they only show them on cubes. Flipping the red face literally flips the plane so either way 1 side is still invisible.

How to actually achieve a both sided plane mesh? For my case, I want both of the sides to be in white color

Image of my model: [image]

EDIT: I have applied the Solidify modifier and it worked!

Comment: How did you do it, did you use an image or is your net modelled, with holes? In that case you can simply extrude it to give it thickness

Comment: Yeah its with holes, Ill try that next time im on pc. However not sure but I think I tried it once and it didnt let me add any thickness

Comment: Maybe show a screenshot of your object or even share the net object itself

Comment: As @moonboots says you should be able to simply extrude it slightly to give it some thickness. Make sure you recalculate the normals (Shift-N in Edit mode) when you've done it though because it's possible to extrude a plane 'in the wrong direction' so that all the face normals are pointing the wrong way!

Comment: In unreal, there should be a "Two sided" option in the Material Editor (Main material node - Details panel). If not, there should be a _no cull_ option for backfaces somehwere.

Comment: Ok I added a screenshot of the model. I tried extruding but it didn't work. When I select it in edit mode and try to flip, it still flips both sides which mean the other side is then wrong. Can't really do the two sided thing in unreal because I'm exporting the model as one, with all objects connected already. As for no cull option in blender, it simply shows me that one side is invisible. I applied solidify modifier to the plane but I'm notsure what it did.

Comment: Is this, at heart, a question about Blender? As @Christopher Bennet has already said : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5qv0YBCE88

Comment: Solidify is the same as extruding, also, when you'll export to Unreal, you'll need to apply the modifier, so you just needed to extrude, and make sure that the faces were correctly oriented (Shift N to recalculate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a "Solidify Modifier" to the plane and check "Apply Modifiers" in the export options.

Comment: This worked for me, however the other side is now darker in color. Is this due to the angle/camera? Or is this a common thing and I need to change something?

Comment: @SimpleBoy Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I didn't say "thanks", I even asked a additional question.